# What should I do when inheriting IDisposable with nothing to dispose?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

[`IEnumerator<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) inherits [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and I have to implement [`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx) even though I have nothing to dispose. Should I still go through the motions?

```
public sealed class NothingEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    private bool disposed;

    public object Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (disposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException("NothingEnumerator");
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        disposed = true;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (disposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException("NothingEnumerator");
        return false;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        if (disposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException("NothingEnumerator");
    }
}
```

Or not?

```
public sealed class NothingEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    public object Current
    {
        get { return default(T); }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
    }
}
```

In other words, do "disposed" objects *have* to throw?

Comment: No - they only have to throw if accessing a disposed object would be _exceptional_.

Comment: If you don't need everything the `IEnumerable` type has to offer, perhaps shall you inherit from something else, or even think of composition over inheritance, maybe.

Comment: I would also implement it explicitly, `IDisposable.Dispose()` then it can only ever be called when cast to `IDisposable`.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller There are all sorts of things you might be doing that would force you to implement an `IEnumerator`, because so many things utilize objects of that type (or `IEnumerable`).  Creating your own slightly different enumerator interface means losing the ability to use all of the library code related to `IEnumerable`.

Comment: In this case, you should probably do what `List<T>.Enumerator` does and just do [nothing](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,d3661cf752ff3f44). It doesn't even keep track of whether it was disposed.

Comment: What's the purpose of this class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only be throwing an exception when the caller is trying to perform an operation that cannot be performed because the object was disposed.  If the operation they're trying to perform will work just fine even after the object is disposed, there's no reason to throw.

Of course, if you *want* to throw, you're certainly welcome to.  It's your decision at the end of the day, but, unlike situations where the method/property has a dependency on a resource that is no longer there, there's just no longer a reason that pretty much *forces* you to throw.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If there are no additional resources to dispose of, provide an empty `Dispose` implementation.

There are other suggestions under "Notes to Implementers" that I would consider as well. (making non-generic properties/methods explicit implementations, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Once an object is disposed, any promise it had made about being usable becomes void, but that does not imply that the object promises to become unusable.  If an object is unable to perform a requested operation as a result of having been disposed, it should throw `ObjectDisposedException` **rather than failing in some other way**, but objects which are capable of honoring a request without needing any outside resources are free to do so.

As to how you should implement `IDisposable`, I would suggest that you follow the `IDisposable` pattern and have a public `Dispose` if you intend to require that all code using your type call `Dispose`, and that you simply include an empty explicit interface implementation if you wish to imply that there is no need to call dispose on references of your type.  If factory methods which are declared as returning your type might return newly-constructed instances of derived types which would need disposal (as is the case with e.g. `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()`) then your type should be designed to encourage client code to call `Dispose`, but otherwise it's probably not necessary.